# How to have individual names as column headers with the attached data in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

This is hard to explain but I'll do my best. So to make it simple, I have 3 tables with the following format:

Creator table

```
id | name
1 | jack
2 | doge
3 | cardano
```

roads

```
id | creator_id | length
1 | 1 | 3
2 | 1 | 2
3 | 3 | 9
4 | 1 | 3
```

Blocks

```
id | creator_id | length
1 | 1 | 4
2 | 1 | 4
3 | 3 | 5
4 | 1 | 3
```

I can't seem to pick out the rows into columns, otherwise I would be posting here but the query I use to bring the data together is:

```
select name, layer, sum(length)
from ( SELect a.name, 'road routes'::text as layer, length
from creator a
LEFT JOIN road_routes b on a.id = b.creator
where a.id in (73, 35, 33, 31)
group by a.name, layer, length
union
SELECT a.name, 'block routes'::text as layer, length
from creator a
LEFT JOIN block_route b on a.id = b.route_creator
where a.id in (73, 35, 33, 31)
group by a.name, layer, length) x
group by layer, name
```

The expected result and what I need is a table with the following output:

```
type | jack | doge | cardano | total
roads | 8 | 0 | 9 | 17
blocks| 11| 0| 5 | 16
```

How to sort the data like this?

Comment: Only tag with the database you are using.  You have enough reputation that you should know that.

Comment: are you looking for alias?..

Comment: http://www.cureffi.org/2013/03/19/automatically-creating-pivot-table-column-names-in-postgresql/

Answer (score 1):

Use **DO** to generate and **PREPARE** query with dynamic columns. Then execute it.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  _query text;
  _name text;
BEGIN
  _name := 'prepared_query';
  _query := '
    SELECT ''roads''::text AS layer
        '||(SELECT ', '||string_agg(' sum(CASE creator_id WHEN '||id::text||' THEN length ELSE 0 END) AS '||quote_ident(name),',') FROM creator)||'
        , sum(length) AS length
    FROM roads
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ''blocks''::text AS layer
        '||(SELECT ', '||string_agg(' sum(CASE creator_id WHEN '||id::text||' THEN length ELSE 0 END) AS '||quote_ident(name),',') FROM creator)||'
        , sum(length) AS length
    FROM blocks';

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'DEALLOCATE '||_name;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN invalid_sql_statement_name THEN
    END;

    EXECUTE 'PREPARE '||_name||' AS '||_query;
END
$$;

EXECUTE prepared_query;
```